# Finding integral by contour integration.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Let $\gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ be the curve $\gamma(t) = e^{2\pi i t}, 0 \le t \le 1$. Find, giving justifications, the value of the contour integral
>   $$
> \int_\gamma \frac{dz}{4z^2-1}.
> $$

I know the Cauchy residue theorem and how to apply it. But I couldn't the let part in the question.

Comment: Hint: Which poles are in the circle?

Comment: Is the given curve unit circle?

Comment: the ''let'' part simply define a circle of radius $1$ centerd at the origin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The curve described parametrically by $\gamma(t)=e^{i2\pi t}$, $0\le t\le 1$ is simply the unit circle centered at $z=0$ (i.e., $|z|=1$).

Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \frac{1}{4z^2-1}\,dz&= \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{4z^2-1}\,dz\\\\
&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{4z^2-1}, z=\pm 1/2\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac14-\frac14 \right)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$